# Keep only the second observation per group in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame ordered by id variables ("city"), and I want to keep the second observation of those cities that have more than one observation.

For example, here's an example data set:

```
city <- c(1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,8)
value <- c(3,5,7,8,2,5,4,2,3,2,3)
mydata <- data.frame(city, value)
```

Then we have:

```
   city value
1     1     3
2     1     5
3     2     7
4     3     8
5     3     2
6     4     5
7     5     4
8     6     2
9     7     3
10    7     2
11    8     3
```

The ideal outcome would be:

```
   city value
2     1     5
3     2     7
5     3     2
6     4     5
7     5     4
8     6     2
10    7     2
11    8     3
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  filter(n() == 1L | row_number() == 2L) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 8 x 2
#    city value
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     5
# 2     2     7
# 3     3     2
# 4     4     5
# 5     5     4
# 6     6     2
# 7     7     2
# 8     8     3
```

or slightly different

```r
mydata %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  slice(min(n(), 2)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

### base R

```r
ind <- ave(rep(TRUE, nrow(mydata)), mydata$city,
           FUN = function(z) length(z) == 1L | seq_along(z) == 2L)
ind
#  [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
mydata[ind,]
#    city value
# 2     1     5
# 3     2     7
# 5     3     2
# 6     4     5
# 7     5     4
# 8     6     2
# 10    7     2
# 11    8     3
```

### data.table

Since you mentioned *"is way bigger"*, you might consider `data.table` at some point for its speed and referential semantics. (And it doesn't hurt that this code is much more terse :-)

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(mydata) # normally one might use setDT(mydata) instead ...
DT[, .SD[min(.N, 2),], by = city]
#     city value
#    <num> <num>
# 1:     1     5
# 2:     2     7
# 3:     3     2
# 4:     4     5
# 5:     5     4
# 6:     6     2
# 7:     7     2
# 8:     8     3
```

Comment: Since you mentioned *"is way bigger"*, I thought I'd add a [tag:data.table] option as well. It has a little learning curve but can be significantly faster.

Answer (score 4):

Here is logic that uses `pmin()` to choose either 2 or 1 depending on the length of the vector of `value`-values:

```
aggregate( value ~ city, mydata, function(x) x[ pmin(2, length(x))] )
  city value
1    1     5
2    2     7
3    3     2
4    4     5
5    5     4
6    6     2
7    7     2
8    8     3
```

The aggregate function delivers vectors of `value` split on the basis of `city`-values.

Comment: this is the most concise one so far and works well for me. Thanks!

Comment: `min` works as well, should be much faster too (not that this dataset will trigger performance issues :-)

Comment: The real dataset is way bigger, I'm testing all answers to see which one is faster. But from what I'm seeing, the result should be very close.

Comment: @r2evans: Yes. I should have written `min`

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  filter(case_when(n()> 1 ~ row_number() == 2,
                   TRUE ~ row_number()== 1)) 

  
   city value
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     5
2     2     7
3     3     2
4     4     5
5     5     4
6     6     2
7     7     2
8     8     3
```

Comment: @IRTFM It gives second one, after adding one more sample to city-1.

Answer (score 2):

If **base R** is ok try this:

*EDIT* (since performance really seems to be important):

Using `if` as a function, should give a 100-fold speed-up in some cases.

```
aggregate( value ~ city, mydata, function(x) `if`(!is.na(x[2]),x[2],x[1]) )

  city value
1    1     5
2    2     7
3    3     2
4    4     5
5    5     4
6    6     2
7    7     2
8    8     3
```

##### Benchmarks

Here're some benchmarks because I was curious. I gathered all solutions and let them run through `microbenchmark`.

Bottom line is `'if'(cond,T,F)` is fastest (22.3% faster than `ifelse` and 17-times faster than the slowest), followed by `ifelse` and `aggregate(pmin)`. Keep in mind that the `data.table` solution only ran on one core. So all speed-up in that package comes from parallelization. No real shocker but interesting nonetheless.

```
library(microbenchmark)

lengths( mydata )
 city value 
20000 20000

c( class(mydata$value), class(mydata$value) )
[1] "integer" "integer"

microbenchmark("aggr_if_function" = { res <- aggregate( value ~ city, mydata, function(x) `if`(!is.na(x[2]),x[2],x[1]) )},
"aggr_ifelse" = { res <- aggregate( value ~ city, mydata, function(x) ifelse(!is.na(x[2]),x[2],x[1]) ) },
"dplyr_filter" = { res <- mydata %>% group_by(city) %>% filter(n() == 1L | row_number() == 2L) %>% ungroup() },
"dplyr_slice" = { res <- mydata %>% group_by(city) %>% slice(min(n(), 2)) %>% ungroup() },
"data.table_single_core" = { res <- DT[, .SD[min(.N, 2),], by = city] },
"aggr_pmin" = { res <- aggregate( value ~ city, mydata, function(x) x[ pmin(2, length(x))] ) },
"dplyr_filter_case_when" = { res <- mydata %>% group_by(city) %>% filter(case_when(n()> 1 ~ row_number() == 2, TRUE ~ row_number()== 1)) },
"group_split_purrr" = { res <- group_split(mydata, city) %>% map_if(~nrow(.) > 1, ~.[2, ]) %>% bind_rows() }, times=50)

Unit: milliseconds
                   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq
       aggr_if_function  175.5104  179.3273  184.5157  182.1778  186.8963
            aggr_ifelse  214.5846  220.7074  229.2062  228.0688  234.1087
           dplyr_filter  585.5275  607.7011  643.6320  632.0794  660.8184
            dplyr_slice  713.4047  762.9887  792.7491  780.8475  803.7191
 data.table_single_core 2080.3869 2164.3829 2240.8578 2229.5310 2298.9002
              aggr_pmin  321.5265  330.5491  343.2752  341.7866  352.2880
 dplyr_filter_case_when 3171.4859 3337.1669 3492.6915 3500.7783 3608.1809
      group_split_purrr 1466.4527 1543.2597 1590.9994 1588.0186 1630.5590
       max neval     cld
  212.6006    50 a      
  253.0433    50 a      
 1066.6018    50   c    
 1304.4045    50    d   
 2702.4201    50      f 
  457.3435    50  b     
 4195.0774    50       g
 1786.5310    50     e
```

Comment: Why `ifelse` here? `if` is faster and more consistent than `ifelse`. (Innovative use of `is.na`, btw, in lieu of `length` or such.)

Comment: For that matter, you might also do `na.omit(x[2:1])[1]` :-)

Comment: @r2evans No specific reason really, other than compactness maybe. Clever use of na.omit though, have to remember that

Answer (score 2):

Another `dplyr` solution:

```
mydata %>% group_by(city) %>%    
  summarize(value=value[pmin(2, n())])
```

Or:

```
mydata %>% group_by(city) %>%
  summarize(value=ifelse(n() >= 2, value[2], value[1]))
```

Both Output:

```
   city value
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     5
2     2     7
3     3     2
4     4     5
5     5     4
6     6     2
7     7     2
8     8     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining `group_split` and `map_if`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

city <- c(1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,8)
value <- c(3,5,7,8,2,5,4,2,3,2,3)
value2 <- c(3,5,7,8,2,5,4,2,3,2,3)
mydata <- data.frame(city, value)

group_split(mydata, city) %>% 
    map_if(~nrow(.) > 1, ~.[2, ]) %>% bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 8 × 2
#>    city value
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5
#> 2     2     7
#> 3     3     2
#> 4     4     5
#> 5     5     4
#> 6     6     2
#> 7     7     2
#> 8     8     3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>